# trying to copy line and modify new copied line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have the following text file:

```
aaaaa dddd  xxxxxx
ddddd rrrr  xxxxxx
wwwww eeee  xxxxxx
```

I would like to have the output like this:

```
aaaaa dddd  xxxxxx
aaaaa dddd  yyyyyy
ddddd rrrr  xxxxxx
ddddd rrrr  yyyyyy
wwwww eeee  xxxxxx
wwwww eeee  yyyyyy
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question after reading [ask]. Currently this is both too broad and asking for homework without any attempt whatsoever.

Comment: With sed, use `p` to print the existing line, then use `s///` to modify the line

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution might look like this:

```
awk -F" " '{print $0 RS $1, $2, " yyyyyy"}' inputfile
```

In this solution, we first print each line (`$0`), then we add a record seperator (RS, which by default equals a line break), then we repeat the first and second column `$1, $2`. Finally, we add manually the string " yyyyyy".

Here is the sample output:

```
aaaaa dddd  xxxxxx
aaaaa dddd  yyyyyy
ddddd rrrr  xxxxxx
ddddd rrrr  yyyyyy
wwwww eeee  xxxxxx
wwwww eeee  yyyyyy
```

Of course, if required, we can use regex to replace `x` by `y` automatically.

```
awk -F" " '{a=$3; gsub(/x/,"y",a); print $0 RS $1,$2," "a}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'p;s/x/y/g' file
```

Print the line then replace all `x`'s with `y`'s and print again.

Or perhaps:

```
sed '/x/p;s//y/g' file
```